# How to take the second derivative of this problem?

Tags: calculus, economics

I am trying to prove all the steps involved in the following paragraph, but I can not find the same result. My second derivative is zero, rather than negative.

> [image: details in this picture link]

Could someone help me please?

Comment: You should show the work you've done. It's possible that you have an easily-identifiable sign error or something. This will help people avoid wasting time (theirs and yours) telling you things you already know, duplicating your effort, or using techniques with which you are not yet familiar.

Comment: I just modified the title question for better understanding

Comment: What the derivative of a problem?!